# Why does std::runtime_error::what() return const char* instead of std::string const&

Tags: c++, string, exception

Why does `std::runtime_error::what()` return `const char*` instead of `std::string const&` ?
In many cases a direct return of a reference to the embedded string would be handy and it could avoid some overhead. So what is the rationale for not returning e.g. a const reference to the internal string in the first place and not offering an overloaded function ? I guess it goes along with a string ctor being able to throw an exception as well but I do not see the risk of returning a string reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::runtime_error` inherits from `std::exception` which defines `virtual const char* what() const throw();` so the simplest response is that it's an overload of the function and that you can be sure that any standard exception defines it in such way. It may (depending on the implementation) be possible to return the `std::string`, but it would be inconsistent with the rest of standard library.

I think the reason why the `what()` returns `const char*` is that you can avoid any operation that can possibly fail (especially that can throw exception). Consider the following code, which shouldn't fail

```
virtual const char* what() const throw() {
    return "An error has occured";
}
```

However in the following code the allocation of `std::string` may fail, throwing an exception:

```
std::string what() const throw() {
    return std::string("An error has occured");
}
```

If the string's constructor threw here, the application would most likely crash no matter what, because the function specifies `throw()`.

Using `std::string` inside an exception introduce the need to allocate memory which may not be possible (note that `std::bad_alloc` inherits from `std::exception` too).

Comment: -1 As of the time of this comment, the code in the answer won't compile, i.e. it's incorrect. The phrasing "may be possible to return the `std::string`" assumes there is a `std::string`, which is not guaranteed, i.e. it's incorrect. The comment that a throwing `what` would introduce "two exceptions thrown at a time" is incorrect: `what` is called, if it is called, in a handler. The comment that there can't be two exceptions thrown at a time is technically incorrect: during stack unwinding `try` blocks can be executed, allowing nested exception throwing. but that seems to be just vague wording.

Comment: OK, I fixed the code and rephrased the note about throwing second exception to make it more clear (I hope). As Alf said, the exception can be thrown in the try block.

Comment: Now the code would compile but would cause Undefined Behavior if used (it returns a pointer to a temporary). The three incorrect technical claims are still there. And this answer still fails to answer the OP's question, the "why", i.e., there's a lot of incorrect claims, there's nonsense UB code, and there's no answer.

Comment: Well, you are right about the code, but its purpose is to illustrate that the ``std::string`` constructor may fail here, but I have no problem changing that. However tell me what are that three incorrect claims. First, I never assumed that there is a std::string. That's why I wrote it _may_ be possible and it is _depending on the implementation_. There is a problem about the claim that it would crash because of propagating two exceptions (will fix that), but a different one - it would crash because it specifies ``throw()``. I don't know what may be the third one.

Answer (score 4):

There is not necessarily an embedded `std::string`. The `what` member function is virtual, i.e. it's designed to be overridden. The chief reason for overriding it is to provide the string in some other way than via the mechanism used by `std::runtime_error` (whatever that mechanism is, most probably a stored `std::string`).

Comment: Good point and one could argue that char is more general. I had a look at the gcc stl implementation where a string is used internally ``class runtime_error : public exception 
  {
    string _M_msg;``  and was a little misguided by that.

Answer (score 1):

While runtime_error does take a std::string as a parameter, so it could hold on to it and return it as you suggest, the what() method is inherited from std::exception, so is more general.

The overhead of throwing an exception is likely to be high already, with stack unwinding, so you should not be worrying about this little extra bit of overhead.

Comment: You are quite right the overhead is obviously negligible. I was more interested in the reasons of why not taking the direct way as your point on inheritance